# Mediametadata error in ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, arraylist, adapter, mediametadataretriever

I've been having a frustrating time extracting `METADATA_KEY_TITLE` of .mp3 files to arraylist and arrayadaper for my ListView to display titles of songs only and in exceptinal cases where title is null, title element returns filename...
Here's my code:

```
final ArrayList<String> myTitu = findTitles(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
metaTitu = new String[myTitu.size()];
for(int j = 0; j<myTitu.size(); j++){
    metaTitu[j] = myTitu.get(j);
}

ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),R.layout.songslist_content,R.id.name_of_song_tab, metaTitu);
lv.setAdapter(adp);

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

public ArrayList<String> findTitles(File root) {
    ArrayList<String> all = new ArrayList<String>();
    File[] files = root.listFiles();
    String names;

    for (File singlet : files) {
        if (singlet.isDirectory() && !singlet.isHidden()) {
            all.addAll(findTitles(singlet));
        } else {
            if (singlet.getName().endsWith(".mp3")){
                try{
                    metameta = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                    metameta.setDataSource(singlet.getPath());
                    names = metameta.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
                    all.add(names);
                } catch (Exception e){
                    names = singlet.getName().toString();
                    all.add(names);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return all;
}
```

Please note that all these are in a Fragment and also debugger complains of a

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()' on a null object reference
```

without pointing to any specific line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, check whether file object `singlet` is not `null` and add `null` check before matching extension with `.mp3` too. You are getting null pointer exception because your are not checking for `null` value inside your **catch** method.

So your code will be as follows :

```
for (File singlet : files) {
        if (null != singlet) {
            if (singlet.isDirectory() && !singlet.isHidden()) {
                all.addAll(findTitles(singlet));
            } else {
                if (null != singlet.getName() && singlet.getName().endsWith(".mp3")){
                    try{
                        metameta = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                        metameta.setDataSource(singlet.getPath());
                        names = metameta.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
                        all.add(names);
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not working still. I'm getting the same error at debugger saying java.string.tostring is null

Comment: I'm trying to experiment other methods binding my array data to map<string, string> then pass it to SimpleAdapter